# Passing wxPython objects as multiprocessor arguments

Tags: python, wxpython, multiprocessing

I'm currently writing a program in python with a gui using wxpython. The program has a function which evaluates several pythonscripts and will therefore hang up the gui. I am trying to use a separate process for this function. The problem is that the function needs a few things from the ui; a listctrl and a textctrl, to update the information about the scripts that have been run. The following error is received when trying to pass wxpython objects to the process

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'PySwigObject'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.PySwigObject failed
```

Method that creates and starts the process:

```
def CreateProcess():
    q = Queue()
    q.put(gui.caselist)
    q.put(gui.textlog)
    p = Process(target=runScripts, args=(q,))
    p.start()
```

Part of the method that is being ran by the process:

```
def runScripts(q):
    caselist = q.get()
    text = q.get()
```

Comment: Read the [LongRunningTasks wiki page](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) for explanations and complete example code on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't. You need to pass the results back and let the GUI thread update the `listctrl` and `textctrl`.

See [this mailing list thread](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/How-to-pickle-a-PySwigObject-td2374154.html) for information about the pickling error.